# TestNG results in Jenkins is showing PASS even if script is changed to generate failed result

Tags: jenkins, testng

I have uploaded the testng-results.xml in a git branch and am using the git repository as a workspace for the Jenkins job.

Since the tests I run on Jenkins are regression tests I would expect the TestNG reports to vary in any event there was a regression defect. I noticed that the TestNG reports displayed on Jenkins is just a readable version of the testng-results.xml file i.e. its a exact copy of the testng-results.xml file in my workspace.

I have changed the test script ChromeTest.f() to purposely fail and still the TestNG results in Jenkins marks it as PASS as per below image:

[image: Jenkins screenshot].

Please find the testng-results.xml file below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" ignored="0" total="9" passed="9">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
<suite name="Default suite" duration-ms="159837" started-at="2017-09-12T16:48:30Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T16:51:10Z">
<groups>
</groups>
<test name="Default test" duration-ms="159837" started-at="2017-09-12T16:48:30Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T16:51:10Z">
<class name="IETests">
<test-method status="PASS" signature="beforeTest()[pri:1, instance:IETests@7921b0a2]" name="beforeTest" duration-ms="18341" 
started-at="2017-09-12T09:48:30Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:48:49Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- beforeTest -->
<test-method status="PASS" signature="f()[pri:2, 
instance:IETests@7921b0a2]" name="f" duration-ms="99893" started-
at="2017-09-12T09:48:49Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:50:29Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- f -->
<test-method status="PASS" signature="afterTest()[pri:3, 
instance:IETests@7921b0a2]" name="afterTest" duration-ms="115" 
started-at="2017-09-12T09:50:29Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:50:29Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- afterTest -->
</class> <!-- IETests -->
<class name="ChromeTest">
<test-method status="PASS" signature="beforeTest()[pri:4, 
instance:ChromeTest@1efbd816]" name="beforeTest" duration-ms="12606" 
started-at="2017-09-12T09:50:29Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:50:41Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- beforeTest -->
<test-method status="PASS" signature="f()[pri:5, 
instance:ChromeTest@1efbd816]" name="f" duration-ms="1087" started-
at="2017-09-12T09:50:41Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:50:42Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- f -->
<test-method status="PASS" signature="afterTest()[pri:6, 
instance:ChromeTest@1efbd816]" name="afterTest" duration-ms="243" 
started-at="2017-09-12T09:50:43Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:50:43Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- afterTest -->
</class> <!-- ChromeTest -->
<class name="FirefoxTest">
<test-method status="PASS" signature="beforeTest()[pri:7, 
instance:FirefoxTest@6a2bcfcb]" name="beforeTest" duration-ms="24220" 
started-at="2017-09-12T09:50:43Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:51:07Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- beforeTest -->
<test-method status="PASS" signature="f()[pri:8, 
instance:FirefoxTest@6a2bcfcb]" name="f" duration-ms="3212" started-
at="2017-09-12T09:51:07Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:51:10Z">
<reporter-output>
 </reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- f -->
<test-method status="PASS" signature="afterTest()[pri:9, 
instance:FirefoxTest@6a2bcfcb]" name="afterTest" duration-ms="83" 
started-at="2017-09-12T09:51:10Z" finished-at="2017-09-12T09:51:10Z">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
</test-method> <!-- afterTest -->
</class> <!-- FirefoxTest -->
</test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
</testng-results>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is just triggering the test in command line and then, like you mention parsing and displaying the xml results file.
Try to run it out of Jenkins, say using Maven, do you see that it fails as you expect? if so, the issue is not related to Jenkins itself and I would concentrate on the test code itself

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using Maven and Junit testing tools.
Also I added my entire project workspace in git before running the test. 
After the build ran in Jenkins I could see the results for each build.
Thank you all for helping